# Torrent peer-to-peer connection

Tags: tcp, udp, forwarding

I used to think my understanding of the TCP and UDP protocols, although limited, is correct. Although recently, when I realized that peers sharing a common torrent can connect to one another through a TCP or UDP protocols without the actual need for port forwarding, I got confused. How does a router know which machine in the local network to forward packets to? Any help in clearing that up would be appreciated. The torrent protocol diagrams and articles on the Internet are greatly simplified, and hence do not contain any information that would help.

Comment: FYI : 90% of Most Routers/Firewalls block UDP !

Comment: And where do you get that statistic?  I've never had an issue with my UDP applications (at home on multiple SOHOs, at coffeeshops or from offices), be it tftp, games, or something custom.

Comment: Most routers block UDP *broadcast* by default.

Comment: @MartinJames Ah, yes, that's probably what sh4nx0r was saying.  Thanks.  Also - what is "90% of most routers"?  Is that 80% of all routes?  I guess it could just be 90% of 50.1% of all routers...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The router (running NAT) tracks all outgoing packets and then allows incoming packets which are responses to those outgoing packets.

So if you make an outgoing TCP connection to google.com:80 then it will allow packets back in (in response) from google.com:80.  If two internal hosts make a connection to the same port it can differentiate them because the local port is different, for example:

1) Host A makes a connection to Google and the router uses its own local port 10001 for the TCP connection

2) Host B makes a similar connection and the router uses its own local port 10002 for the TCP connection

If a packet comes in from google.com:80 and its addressed for the port 10001 on the router's WAN IP then the router knows to send it to Host A.  If its addressed for port 10002 the router knows to send it to Host B.

If you have two peer to peer hosts behind routers (two NATs) then there is no way to establish the connection except that if there is something to transfer information about each others IPs (i.e. a server they can both use to exchange information) they can try to guess what port the router will choose as a local port and then start sending each other data on that port, to the routers WAN IP.  Because both routers see data going OUT they then set up a rule to allow data IN.  If the ports are guessed correctly then the packets from each side can get through because both routers have a rule set up.  This is called UDP/TCP Hole Punching.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

I believe Skype is an example of a app which uses UDP and does hole punching.

Comment: Thank you for an insightful response! I believe I now sufficiently understand the subject to let my mind go to rest... for now.

By the way, Skype is a clever beast. I think it might detect when you're in a conversation with a person from your local network (I could once talk to my sister while the router was still connecting to the Internet after a reboot)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, since you haven't qualified your term router with 'NAT', then the answer is that the router uses ARP to determine the MAC address of the target host and then sends and ethernet frame with that MAC address as the target address.

But I think that was not what you meant.

You mean how does a NATting router know where to forward inbound packets?

The answer is that the router maintains a list of active "connections" to enable it to be able to do address translation. It uses the outside port number to map to an inside host address and port number. In the case of TCP, the concept of a "connection" is simply whether there is a TCP connection (though usually with a timeout to stop leakage). In the case of UDP it's harder because there is no UDP connection *per se*, so it is generally a case of tracking it by timeout alone.